# Is the argument used in this proof that $k=1$ logically sound, where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$?

Tags: solution-verification, conjectures, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

Euler proved that a hypothetical odd perfect number $N$, if one exists, must have the so-called *Eulerian form* $N=q^k n^2$, where $q$ is the *special prime* satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

It is known that
$$q < \frac{2n^2}{D(n^2)} \leq q + 1,$$
where $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$ is the *deficiency* of the positive integer $x$, and $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ is the *classical sum of divisors* of $x$.  (Denote the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.)

It has been recently shown that
$$I(n^2) > \frac{2(q - 1)}{q} + \frac{1}{qn^2}.$$
This is equivalent to
$$q\bigg(2 - I(n^2)\bigg) < 2 - \frac{1}{n^2}.$$

Since
$$\frac{1}{2 - I(n^2)} \leq \frac{q+1}{2},$$
then the assumption
$$\frac{q+1}{2} \leq \frac{q}{2 - (1/n^2)}$$
is equivalent to $k \neq 1$, since we then have
$$\frac{q+1}{2} \leq \frac{q}{2 - (1/n^2)} < \frac{1}{2 - I(n^2)} = \frac{n^2}{D(n^2)} \leq \frac{q+1}{2},$$
whence the equation
$$\frac{n^2}{D(n^2)} = \frac{q+1}{2}$$
**cannot be satisfied**.  This shows the equivalence between $k \neq 1$ and
$$\frac{q+1}{2} \leq \frac{q}{2 - (1/n^2)}.$$

But the inequality
$$\frac{q+1}{2} \leq \frac{q}{2 - (1/n^2)}$$
is equivalent to
$$2q + 2 - \frac{q + 1}{n^2} \leq 2q,$$
which in turn, is equivalent to
$$n^2 \leq \frac{q+1}{2}.$$

This last inequality implies that
$$n^2 \leq \frac{q+1}{2} < q < q^2,$$
from which it [follows](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html) that $k = 1$.

We therefore have the **true** implication
$$k \neq 1 \implies k = 1.$$

This means that $k = 1$ *holds*.

Here then is my:

> **QUESTION:** Does this "proof" hold water?  If it does not, where is the error, and can it be mended so as to produce a valid argument?

**Edited in response to a comment from Bill Dubuque - 07/07/2022**

So, basically my question is whether the inequality
$$\frac{q+1}{2} \leq \frac{q}{2-(1/n^2)}$$
is *indeed* equivalent to $k \neq 1$, though I think this inquiry is fairly obvious from the context.

Comment: This site is not meant to be a general proof checking machine. If you have a specific mathematical question about a specific step in the proof then please state that, and explain why you question it. Otherwise the question will likely be closed and deleted.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Is it not the case that **[proof-verification]** is an existing tag here at MSE?

Comment: Where are you using the fact that $k\neq 1$ in your proof of the equivalence? It looks like you're just proving that $(q+1)/2 \leq q/(2-1/n^2)$ is always false, regardless of the value of $k$.

Comment: @ThomasBloom: I am actually using the equivalence $k=1 \iff {n^2}/D(n^2) = (q+1)/2$.

Comment: @ARNIE Yes, but to properly use that tag it is essential to supply said context else your question may \ be closed & deleted.

Comment: But your chain of inequalities gives a contradiction whenever $n^2/D(n^2) \leq (q+1)/2$, which your first display equation claims is always true anyway. So the value of $k$ is irrelevant, and $(q+1)/2\leq q/(2-1/n^2)$ is always false.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Is the context not clear enough for you? Seriously?

Comment: @ThomasBloom: Ahh I get your point now. If you could just please write an answer, I will be more than happy to upvote and then accept it.

Comment: @ARNIE "said context" refers to that specified in my first comment above, i.e. the *specific* step of the proof that you have doubts about, and why so.

Comment: @BillDubuque: What "said context" was lacking from my self-evident original post?

Comment: You did not say which step you doubted, and why so. We can't read your mind.

Comment: @BillDubuque: But is it not self-evident from my original post?

Comment: Readers should not have to search through a long post and make guesses about what the precise question is. It should be *explicitly* stated. If a hundred readers waste 5 min's doing so then that wastes much community effort.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Say that again to hundreds (or thousands even) of similar askers.

Comment: We have, but most of those posts have been deleted by now since they were not improved to meet quality standards.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Is my present post **too long** for you?

Comment: Nobody said anything about it being "too long".

Comment: Well, apparently you just said, @BillDubuque: "Readers should not have to search through a long post..." What are you implying then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written is a valid (assuming all of the statements you quote are correct) proof that $\frac{q+1}{2} \leq \frac{q}{2-1/n^2}$ is always false. The value of $k$ is irrelevant.

(And so it is not surprising that you can 'deduce' $k=1$ from the assumption that $\frac{q+1}{2} \leq \frac{q}{2-1/n^2}$ - false statements imply everything!)